# Stack implementation using Array (ways to improve code)

Tags: c++, stack

Need to implement stack using array only, methods: *push, pop, print*.
The task itself: 
Implement stack using only array. The only time compiler should allocate memory is through *set_size* function. 
The current code version works good enough, but I'm looking for ways to improve it's exec-time / complexity / readability etc. Any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

````
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <class T>
class Stack
{
 int size = 0;
 T* Array;
 int top = 0;

public:
 Stack(size_t Size);
 ~Stack()
 {
     delete[] Array;
 }
 void push(T element);
 void pop();
 void print();
};
template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(size_t Size)
{
 size = Size;
 top = -1;
 Array = new T[size];
}
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(T element)
{
 if (top >= (size - 1))
 {
     std::cout << "overflow" << std::endl;
 }
 else
 {
     Array[++top] = element;
 }
}
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::pop()
{
 if (top < 0)
 {
     std::cout << "underflow" << std::endl;
 }
 else
 {
     std::cout << Array[top--] << std::endl;
 }

}
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::print()
{
 if (top == -1)
 {
     std::cout << "empty" << std::endl;
 }
 int i = top;
 while (i > -1)
 {
     std::cout << Array[i--] << " ";
 }
 std::cout << std::endl;
}
template <class T>
Stack<T> set_size(int Size)
{
 return Stack<T>(Size);
}

int main()
{
 auto stack = set_size<std::string>(5);
 stack.push("hello");
 stack.push("hi");
 stack.push("hey");
 stack.push("greetings");
 stack.push("welcome");
 stack.print();
 stack.pop();
 stack.pop();
 stack.print();
 return 0;
}```
````

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem comes from the type conversion between your stack pointer `top` to your stack size `size`.

`top` is an `int`, which is a **signed** type.
`size_t` is an **unsigned** integral type.

When testing `(top >= (size - 1))`, `top` is converted to an `unsigned int` and then considered as `UINT_MAX` instead of `-1`, which is always >= to any other `unsigned int`.

You can either use a `size_t` as your stack pointer, which means that you cannot use negative value, or convert `(size - 1)` to a signed value before comparing to `top` (but this last solution means that you must ensure that the size you specify as a size_t is not too big to be converted to a signed int).

Your print function has also two issues:

- in your first test, you assign `-1` to `top` instead of comparing the values
- you change your `top` stack pointer, so that you stack is in an inconsistant state after a call to `print()`

Comment: Thank you very much! 
Any other thoughts on how to improve it?

Comment: Your `pop()` function does not return any value. I suppose it is not what you need in this exercice. When unstacking a value, you are supposed to know the unstacked value. The stack would be quite useless otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your branch predictions are possibly not optimal. You should inspect the resulting assembly to see if the prediction bets on the `if` rather than on `else` in your `if...else` constructs (it will probably predict the `if` and in this case you should put the common case in the `if`).
2. You should pass the arguments by reference and not by value. It doesn't matter in case of simple integers but if your `T` becomes something more complex, it will result in redundant copy upon `push`.